# Substitute apricot with some other fruit in this Sunny-Side-Up Apricot Pastries recipe

Tags: substitutions, fruit, pastry

[This recipe](http://cookingwiththemasters.com/2010/08/puff-pastry-julia-child-michel-richard/) (scroll down to the bottom of the page) calls for apricot to use on the topping of the pastries. What fruit do you recommend to use that will be as good, along with its jam for the glaze? What about mango? I have no idea about cooked mango, have never eaten one!

Comment: why do you not want to use apricot? without knowing that, people may recommend things that still don't work for you

Comment: @KateGregory: I don't have apricot at home and I'd use other fruits  that I have in the fridge. (mango, apple or some other fruit that people recommend)

Comment: Any stone fruit or berry would work well in this application.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting. If you want it to taste like apricot, nothing except apricot will work. If it is OK for you to taste like something else, any fruit will do, and none is better than the other one. Can you give some criteria - what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to maintain a similar color/texture/firmness, then cling peaches are the way to go. Except they are almost always found canned (I live in California and sometimes find them fresh at farmers markets where vendors come from the Sacramento valley).

I'm a fan of the pear.  Bosc and Anjou will hold up well during cooking (Bartlett pears may fall apart).

Both should work well with the pastry cream and vanilla in the recipe.

If you end up using pears, consider adding just a hint of almond extract or amaretto to the pastry creme.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the link for the recipe, but  if it calls for fresh apricots you can substitute

- Peaches. Freestone vs Cling refers to whether the flesh  is attached to the pit.  when you slice  the fruit. We get Michigan peaches in Chicago. There is no appreciable taste difference between the two.

I would skin the peaches.You dunk them in simmering water for about 30 seconds, remove and rub the skin off with a paper towel

Use peach jam for the glaze. Add a bit of lemon juice to punch up the flavor.

- Some variety of plums. Look for firm fruit which the store or vendor says are sweet. For this I would use  a strained  orange marmalade for the glaze, again correcting with lemon juice for tartness. Plums should not be skinned first.
- Nectarines. I would not  skin these. I use nectarines interchangeably with mangoes in a fruit salad . For a glaze try red currant jelly. Smuckers makes a nationally  distributed brand in the US but my international supermarket has several alternatives

It is a matter of personal preference but I think you should confine your substitute  to stone fruits rather than apples and  pears because of the different flavor and texture profiles.

Apples have a lot of pectin and can be used as a base for a glaze which is flavored with something to complement the stone fruit you use.